# IIS: What tools can we use to read .evt file

Tags: iis

As title said, I can what tool to read .evt file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um, Event Viewer?

Comment: I think he asked for multiple tools. :-)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the built in Event Viewer app there are quite a few script\parsing utilities out there to help with more advanced\structured processing of Eventlog\evt files.

[Perl's win32::EventLog](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-EventLog/)
[Microsoft's Log Parser](http://forums.iis.net/default.aspx?GroupID=51)

One problem you may have is that older format event logs (.evt from W2K3\XP era systems) don't always play nicely on newer systems which use the binary .evtx format - the [WEVTUTIL command](http://blogs.technet.com/neilcar/archive/2007/08/15/plogparser-event-logs-and-vista.aspx) can be used to convert the former to the latter.